# Как работает директива using?

Tags: c#, excel, using

Хочу попробовать работать с Excel в приложении C# WPF.
Добавил в references Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel версии 15.0.0.0.
Скопировал и вставил в свой класс пример:

```
        // Создаём экземпляр нашего приложения
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // Создаём экземпляр рабочий книги Excel
        Excel.Workbook workBook;
        // Создаём экземпляр листа Excel
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
```

Независимо от задаваемого using:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Application подсвечивается красным. При этом если убрать из примера "**Excel.**", то при 
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
всё прекрасно работает.
Так же работает если вместо
**using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;**
задать
**using Excel1=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;**
то тоже прокатывает: **Excel1.Application**
Вопрос: 
Почему вышеопробованные директивы не помогли, и можно ли добиться, чтобы с Excel. (как было в примере) тоже работало?

Comment: [Директива using (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7FZP.png).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что класс добавил в отдельную папку Excel. Соответственно и namespace стал содержать Excel. Он и конфликтовал с псевдонимом.